# storing Output of plsql query in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sqlplus

I'm not getting any output to my FILE for query. while I'm running in oracle I can see the counts.
Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

    ORACLE_HOME=*path*
    TNS_ADMIN=*path*

    export ORACLE_HOME
    export TNS_ADMIN

    FILE="/tmp/score_cnt.txt"

    sqlplus -S user/pass@service<< EOF

    spool $FILE
        select count(*) from score_tbl
         spool off
    exit;
    EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like passing the `*nix` variable to `SQL*Plus` is messing the things around here.

As far as I understand, you wish to pass the file name in the script, then the easiest mechanism would be to define it as `SPOOL` File directly (instead of getting it parametrized).

Moreover you can add some really useful `SET` parameters to beautify the output.

```
sqlplus -S user/pass@service << EOF
SET LINESIZE 32000
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET WRAP OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF

spool /tmp/score_cnt.txt
    select count(*) from score_tbl;
     spool off

EOF
```

> PS - `EOF` doesn't require additional `exit` in sqlplus & `select`
>   statement must end with a `;`